# Emacs shows white space and newline characters

Tags: characters

What kind of feature is this and how to disable it?

[image]

I've used the wrong shortcut, but I don't remember what I pressed. When I kill the buffer and open the same file again I have those markers.
The thing is global because When I reload the other buffer I get the same markers. Is there a way to turn this off, without closing Emacs?

I was searching for different things but all I have is whitespace-mode that I use for different purposes (to highlight trailing whitespace and tabs). I think it's some fundamental function in Emacs, but I don't know how to name it (to find it in docs).

Answer (score 1):

I've found it it was <kbd>M-c</kbd> <kbd>M-w</kbd> I make this accidentally when using <kbd>M-c</kbd> <kbd>w</kbd> (I use this to toggle indentation modes between 4 and 2 spaced). The key sequence was mapped to `web-mode-whitespaces-show`. Web-mode is my main mode I use for editing TypeScript files.

Comment: You might want to mention how you found it, if you think what you did to find it might help others. Thx.

Comment: @Drew It was an accident like the first time I tried the same key with **CTRL** and the markers disappeared.